# How to find the accuracy of a set partitioning?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, sets

Suppose that there are $k$ sets $S_1, S_2, S_3, \dots, S_k$.

The numbers $N = \{1, 2, \dots,n\}$ are distributed into these sets equally.

Say that we partition $N$ into $m$ sets $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_m$.

The problem is to find how accurate is our partitioning.
However, the *accuracy* is not finding the exact same sets, but putting the same elements into the same set.
For instance:

$S_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$
$S_2 = \{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$
$S_3 = \{13,14,15,16,17,18\}$

and

$P_1 = \{1,2\}$
$P_2 = \{3,4,5\}$
$P_3 = \{6,7,8,9\}$
$P_4 = \{10,11,12\}$
$P_5 = \{13,14,15,16\}$
$P_6 = \{17\}$
$P_7 = \{18\}$

This partitioning is almost accurate because if we were to put $6$ into $P_2$ instead of $P_3$, then none of the sets would contain elements those do not belong to the same set in the original sets.

However,
$P_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
$P_2 = \{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18\}$

is a very inaccurate partitioning because half of the elements in each set is from a different set.

My questions are:
1. Is there a name for this problem?
2. Is this problem NP-Hard?
3. How can I define a metric for the accuracy of the partitioning?
4. How can I find how accurate a partitioning is?

Comment: You really need to formally define "accuracy" to give this problem a meaning. We can't discuss hardness till the decision problem is well-defined.